# Shelve KeyError when putting a shelve array into a variable

Tags: python-3.x, shelve

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shelve.py", line 111, in __getitem__
    value = self.cache[key]
KeyError: 'lb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "imgbot.py", line 85, in on_message
    lead = getlb()
  File "imgbot.py", line 75, in getlb
    sortedlb = sortlb()
  File "imgbot.py", line 50, in sortlb
    utemp = ulbs['lb']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shelve.py", line 113, in __getitem__
    f = BytesIO(self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)])
KeyError: b'lb'
```

Relevant function:

```
def sortlb():
    ulbs = shelve.open('leaderboard')
    utemp = ulbs['lb']
    lbs.close()
    ret = ['Leaderboard:']
    pos = 0;
    while len(temp) > 0:
        largest = -1;
        lindex = 0;
        luser = ''
        rentry = ''
        pos = pos+1
        for entry in utemp:
            id = entry[:x]
            name = entry[x+1:p]
            points = entry[p+1:]
            if points > largest:
                largest = points
                lindex = utemp.index(entry)
                luser = name
        rentry = pos+'. '+luser
        ret.append(str(lindex)+'. '+rentry)
        del utemp[utemp.index(lindex)]

    return ret
```

Basically I'm trying to sort a list of users/points into most to least points, in a "username/userid,points" format because I didn't know a better way to do it, lol

Comment: The only relevant line here is `utemp = ulbs['lb']` - the KeyError is telling you that there is no such key in your shelved dictionary. Perhaps `print(list(ulbs.keys()))` to make sure it's opening the right file. `shelve.open('leaderboard')` won't give an error if that file doesn't exist, it will simply create a new shelf.

Comment: turns out the issue was caused by me not actually creating the key in another function because the function was never being called when I though it was.

wouldn't have figured it out without your advice to print the list of keys though, so thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :)